# Php process form

Tags: php

Here's a code snippet of a php form process which I am having trouble with, I'm unsure how to get the telephone number ('tel') to display in the responding email:

```
$success = false;
$fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['fname'] ) : "";
$sname = isset( $_POST['sname'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['sname'] ) : "";
$email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
**$tel = isset( $_POST['tel'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['tel']** ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $fname && $sname && $tel && $email && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $fname . " " . $sname . "  <" . $email . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: given you don't actually **USE** $tel anywhere, no wonder it doesn't show up in your email.

Comment: why don't you just use `trim(strip_tags($_POST['field_name']));` instead of that the preg_replace

Comment: Marc B how do you know im not using $tel anywhere??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix to get the telephone number in your message is just to append it to the message variable.

Something like this :

```
$tel = isset( $_POST['tel'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['tel']** ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

$message .= "Telephone: ".$tel;
```

Comment: Thanks mate thats what I was looking for although I thought I had already tried it, obviously I didnt!